# Populating a DataGridView using a DataTable and TableAdapter based on a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, data-binding

I am pretty new to C# (and Visual Studio) and I've run into a problem.

I have an Access database that I'm using, and I have need to fill a DataGridView using a SELECT statement. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Opened up my DataSet.xsd file.
2. Created a new DataTable (called MyNewTable) and TableAdapter based on the SELECT statement I want to run.
3. Went to my Form.cs file, added a DataGridView, and set its DataSource to `Other Data Sources > Project Data Sources > DataSet > MyNewTable`.
4. Build and run the program.

When I run it, however, it doesn't show any rows. So to check and make my SELECT statement actually returns rows, I head back over to my DataSet.xsd file and right click on MyNewTable and select `Preview Data`. Sure enough, when I hit the Preview Data button, there are two rows in the table.

Just to check and make sure I wasn't doing something wrong in the binding, I tried going back and setting the DataSource to a different table (a real table from the database, not one based on a SELECT statement.) When I reran it with the real table it showed data.

So what am I doing wrong? What is the proper procedure for creating a DataGridView that displays the results of a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2):

simple ..

see first of all go to the xaml of your form.. find the datagridview that you dragged ..
in there you have to find **autogeneratecolumns** property , then set it to **true**

after that come back to your c# code and do it like this...

```
yourdataset x = new yourdataset();
 yourtableadapter y = new yourtableadapter();
 y.Fill(x.yourtable);
 datagridview1.itemsource = x.yourtable.defaultview ;
```

Please keep in mind .. this is not accurate code ... it was just for the sake of illustration.. 
Your dataset and tablenames might be different.. so use appropriate names.. 
Any problems let me know ..